# express-validator isDate and isISO8601 are always false

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm trying to validate a date. I have tried everything I can but I have not found a solution. Input {"dob": "2002-10-02"}

```
'use strict'

var validator = require('validator');
var controller = {

    create: (req,res) =>{

        //pick parameters
        var parameters =  req.body;
     
        //validator
        
        try {
        
            //not working (always returns false)
            //var validate_dob = validator.isDate(parameters.dob + '');
            //also not working (always returns false)
            //var validate_dob = validator.isISO8601(parameters.dob + '');

            

        } catch (error) {
            
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: error
            });
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you mention tag `express-validator`, but in your middleware you use pure `validator`.

Here I am putting an example using the express-validator lib (version 6.6.0). To use validate body parameters (login and password). But you can get the idea and pick the validation for your date from the validators list. [Reference](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js).

***server/validators/login.validator.js***

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.validationBodyRules = [
    body('login', 'login is required').exists(),
    body('password', 'password is required').exists(),
    body('login', 'login is required').notEmpty(),
    body('password', 'password is required').notEmpty()
];

exports.checkRules = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    next();
};
```

Here is the routes file

***server/routes/login.route.js***

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const loginService = require('../controllers/login.controller');
const loginValidator = require('../validators/login.validator');

router.post('/login', loginValidator.validationBodyRules, loginValidator.checkRules, loginService.hashPassword, loginService.lookupLogin, loginService.logEmployee);

module.exports = router;
```

***server/controllers/login.controller.js***

```
const postgres = require('../../lib/postgres');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.logEmployee = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ token: 'Bearer ' + jwt.sign(req.employee, process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: 1800 }) });//expires in 1800 seconds
    res.end();
};

exports.hashPassword = (req, res, next) => {
    crypto.scrypt(req.body.password.toString(), 'salt', 256, (err, derivedKey) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'Could not do login', param: req.params.id }] });
        }
        req.body.kdfResult = derivedKey.toString('hex');
        next();
    });
};

exports.lookupLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT e.employee_id, e.login FROM employee e WHERE e.login=$1 AND e.password = $2';
    postgres.query(sql, [req.body.login, req.body.kdfResult], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'Could not do login', param: req.params.id }] });
        }
        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'User or password does not match', param: req.params.id }] });
        }
        req.employee = result.rows[0];
        next();
    });
};
```

But you can use the ideas here to use a date validator.

If you need a more complete example, please, let me know.

Comment: yes it is true it is the validator library, what I do not understand is in the case of dates, I need to validate a date of birth and these specific tools to validate dates do not work for me